# Implementation of one-time promotional codes in the application. Android development

Tags: java, android, mobile

At the moment I'm writing a code for promotional codes. The problem is that I don't know how to implement a one-time code, that is, a user can use them an unlimited number of times.

My code:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.content.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.send); 
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.promo);
                    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.ident);
                    String txt = editText.getText().toString();         

                    if (txt.equals("ILIKENEKO") || txt.equals("NEWYEAR2023")){                      textView.setText("Successfully!");
                        }
                    else{
                            textView.setText("Promo code used or expired!");
                        }
                }
        });
    }
}
```

I tried to implement it through `SharedPreference`, but it all ended in failure.

Comment: Can multiple devices use the same promo code?

Comment: **Yes, they can.**  just promo codes will change with app updates

Comment: Are you aware that people could just analyze your app and read out the promo codes if they are stored within the app?

Comment: We are not trying to somehow hide the data now, because there is nothing to hide. If you think this decision is stupid, then just accept

Comment: I want to make sure you know about that. Can you show your attempt with shared preferences?

Comment: I am writing consider application for private use. you can consider it as for "general development", you don't have to worry about security. There were attempts, but this is already a modified source code https://pastebin.com/yUfFFcpB

Comment: With that attempt using shared preferences, does it work after restarting the application (use the promo code, restart it and then it's blocked)?

Comment: I'm sorry, but the issue has already been resolved by self. thank you for the discussion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.content.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    SharedPreferences sPref;

    final String SAVED_PROMO = "Null";
    final String SAVED_2PROMO = "Null";
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.send);
        
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.promo);
                    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.ident);
                    String txt = editText.getText().toString();         
                    
                    if (txt.equals("ILIKENEKO")){
                        sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                        String savedText = sPref.getString(SAVED_PROMO, "");
                        if(!savedText.equals("ILIKENEKO")){
                            textView.setText("Успешно!");
                            sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                            Editor ed = sPref.edit();
                            ed.putString(SAVED_PROMO, txt);
                            ed.commit();
                        }
                    else{
                            textView.setText("Просрочено!");
                        }
                }
                else if (txt.equals("NEWYEAR2023")){
                    sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                    String savedText = sPref.getString(SAVED_2PROMO, "");
                    if(!savedText.equals("NEWYEAR2023")){
                        textView.setText("Успешно!");
                        sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                        Editor ed = sPref.edit();
                        ed.putString(SAVED_2PROMO, txt);
                        ed.commit();
                    }
                    else{
                        textView.setText("Просрочено!");
                    }
                
                }
        }});
    }

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).